# Can a I control the type of the return value of a method by passing different parameters to it?

Tags: java, generics

To give a concrete example, I am looking to do something like the following (contrived example, of course):

```
Interface Animal {}
Interface AnimalImpl {}
Interface Lion extends Animal {}
Interface Hippo extends Animal {}
Class LionImpl implements Lion, AnimalImpl {}
Class HippoImpl implements Hippo, AnimalImpl {}
```

Then we have a zoo which can have at most one Animal of each type.  It contains something like a map from class to AnimalImpl.

Then I would want to call something like

`zoo.getAnimal(Lion.class)` and have it return a Lion.  I can have it return an AnimalImpl, but then I have to cast to a Lion - I'm looking to avoid that cast.  (And likewise, if I called `zoo.getAnimal(Hippo.class)`, it should return a Hippo.)

Comment: This sounds a lot like dependency injection. You may want to google for that term, and see some of the common libraries/frameworks for it in Java. (I've used Guice and Spring-Boot in the past, but there are others.)

Answer (score 0):

Not as written.  The static return type is 'AnimalImpl'.  But generics may be able to solve your problem; something like

```
class zoo {
    <T> T getAnimal(Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics, but, you don't want to use instances of `java.lang.Class` as the carrier of choice like this. It's extremely inflexible. For example, the job 'hey, here is an instance of `Class<Lion>`, now you get to make a lion' **does not work** - you have to hack your way out of the typesystem do to that, and just.. at runtime use reflection to ask for the no-args constructor, call it, and pray that it works. There is no way to tell the compiler that `Lion` (the class) *must* have a no-args public constructor, and that it can't be abstract either.

The better solution is to make... a factory! (Yes, java is the clichéd 'oooh factories everywhere' language, but that's just people who misunderstand what this is or cribbing notes off of code bases that took it too far. The concept is quite useful, don't let the memes mislead you).

You want the concept of 'a thing that can describe an animal and make new instances of that animal, using this specific type-system-based specification'.

Thus, you want something like:

```
public interface AnimalMaker<A extends Animal> {
  A create();
  String describe();
}

public abstract class Animal {}

public class Lion extends Animal {}

public class LionMaker implements AnimalMaker<Lion> {
  public Lion create() { return new Lion(); }
  public String describe() { return "Describe lion here"; }
}
```

and then you can make a method that makes lions like so:

```
public class Zoo {
  public <A extends Animal> A importAnimal(AnimalMaker<A> maker) {
    A animal = maker.create();
    animals.add(animal);
    return animal;
  }
}
```

and use *that* like so:

```
void specializeAsLionZoo() {
  LionMaker maker = new LionMaker();
  Lion newLion = zoo.importAnimal(maker);
}
```